# The number of combinations of the number 196225

Tags: python, list, count, combinations

I wanted to write a program that will show the number of combinations of the number 196225 but I failed because it showed very strange numbers and I can't quite understand why
my code:

```
list = []
liczba = [1,9,6,2,2,5]
n_num = 0
iter=0

#ijlkmn

for i in range(6):
  n_num = liczba[i]*10**5
  for j in range(6):
    if j != i:
      n_num += liczba[j]*10**4
      for l in range(6):
        if l != i and l != j:
          n_num += liczba[l]*10**3
          for k in range(6):
            if k != i and k != j and k!= l:
              n_num += liczba[k]*10**2
              for m in range(6):
                if m != i and m != j and m != l and m!= k:
                  n_num += liczba[m]*10
                  for n in range(6):
                    if n != i and n != j and n != l and n!= k and n!= m:
                      n_num += liczba[n]
                      if (n_num in list) == False:
                        list.append(n_num)
                        iter += 1
```

I know it looks very primitive but I only wanted the result which turned out to be incorrect, here are some of its numbers ~

```
196225, 196277, 196502, 196554, 197076, 197098, 199723, 199775, 200040
```

could someone tell me where did these numbers come from?

Comment: You just want the number of combinations or the combinations?

Comment: What does "combinations of the number 196225" mean?

Comment: don't use the variable name list as it is already a keyword in python.

Comment: Your code doesn't account for the fact that there are duplicate values in the list, so there are duplicate permutations.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make all the possible numbers using tose digits , you can use `itertools` module :

```
import itertools

liczba = [1, 9, 6, 2, 2, 5]
numbers = itertools.permutations(liczba, 6)
for num in numbers:
  print(num)
```

Comment: Yeah but what's wrong with the provided code?

Comment: @kpie: It is 10 times as long, for one thing.

Comment: Yes but why isn't it producing expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to previous answers on each of your internal loops. Because the value of n_num is not reset at each iteration. For example:

```
digits = [1,2,3]

for k in range(3):
    n_num = digits[k]*10**2
    for k2 in range(3):
        if k2!=k:
            n_num += digits[k2]*10
            print(n_num)
```

prints

```
120
150
210
240
310
330
```

because when k2 = 2 the first time, 30 is added to 120 yielding 150... etc etc

Answer (score 0):

I see what's wrong with your code - let's look into smaller example to see it clearly and find a solution

```
liczba = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(3):
    n_num = liczba[i] * 10 ** 2 # it start with 1 * 100 = 100, good one!
    for j in range(3):
        if j != i: # for j = 0 it just pass
            n_num += liczba[j] * 10 # j = 1, n_num is now 100 + 20 = 120
            for l in range(3):
                if l != i and l != j: we skip 0 and 1
                    n_num += liczba[l] # n_num = 123, great
                    list.append(n_num)
```

Now we back to second loop:

```
    for j in range(3): # j jumps to 2
        if j != i:
            n_num += liczba[j] * 10 # wait - here is the problem, our n_num should be 100 here again but now it's 123, so we add 30 to previous solution
            for l in range(3):
                if l != i and l != j: # l = 1
                    n_num += liczba[l] # adding 2, but instead of 100 + 30 + 2 we have 123 + 30 + 2
                    list.append(n_num)
```

How to fix it? Very simple - you can just calculate number once at the end. You have all indexes already, so write

```
n_num = liczba[i] * 10 ** 5 + liczba[j] * 10 ** 4 + ...
```

And one small hint for the end - if you use `set` instead of `list` you won't need a check if n_num is already in result.